# get() returning null from firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My documentSnapshot is returning null, although the data is there, document Id is also known and prints to console. However, retrieving data returning null.

```
PetUser senderL = PetUser();
PetUser receiverL = PetUser();

getUpdatedChatterPro() async {
  var snaps = await ServerAPI()
      .chatsCollection
      .doc(widget.id)
      .collection('messages')
      .orderBy('time', descending: false)
      .limitToLast(1);

  snaps.get().then((value) {
    setState(() {
      senderLast = value.docs.last['senderId'];
      receiverLast = value.docs.last['receiverId'];
    });
  });
}

getReceiverProfile() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(receiverLast)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    setState(() {
      receiverL = PetUser.fromJson(value.data()!);
    });
    return receiverL;
  });
}

getSenderProfile() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(senderLast)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    setState(() {
      senderL = PetUser.fromJson(value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
    });
    return senderL;
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  getUpdatedChatterPro();
  getReceiverProfile();
  getSenderProfile();
}

debugPrint(
    '${widget.id}, $senderLast, $receiverLast, ${senderL.imageUrl}, ${senderL.name}, '
    '${receiverL.name}, ${receiverL.imageUrl}');
```

Printing values to console prints IDs, but images and names return null.

Comment: You have async calls in your initState.  Those will not be completed before the first build() begins.  Do you have a FutureBuilder in your build()?

Comment: ohh.. i c.. i will test with moving them to the main widget. I dont have FutureBuilder(). only streambuilder...

Comment: It worked, thank u, Randal! I now realise that all three asyncs were running at the same time. Moving my other methods to the main widget did it.